# How do I align the navigation buttons on a full width responsive slider

Tags: javascript, html, css

**Scenario**

I'm having a problem working out the best solution to responsively align the previous and next navigation buttons using the [Owl Carousel v2](http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/).

I need the arrows as they have been styled to fit within the offset column of the centered container and maintain their overlay position down to 767px where the layout changes. Currently they are just positioned to edge of the screen.

There is an example fiddle posted below, but the general principle is that there is a full width background image that remains for the first two slides (rather than sliding the same image twice) and only the center text changes. Then the background changes on the 3rd slide along with the text.

**Code**

HTML

```
<div class="background-full background-one">
    <div class="carousel">
        <div class="item">
            <div class="container carousel-container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-5 hidden-xs col-sm-offset-1 carousel-text">
                         <h1>Section Title</h1>

                        <p class="hidden-xs">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
                        consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor 
                        incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim 
                        ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco 
                        laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
                        <p class="hidden-xs">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
                        consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor 
                        incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim 
                        ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco 
                        laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
                        <button>Link</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-5 col-xs-12 carousel-image">
                        <img alt="" class="img-responsive" src="http://www.placehold.it/458x376" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="container carousel-container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-5 hidden-xs col-md-offset-1 carousel-text">
                        <h1>Section Title 2</h1>

                        <p class="hidden-xs">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
                        consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor 
                        incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim 
                        ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco 
                        laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
                        <p class="hidden-xs">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
                        consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor 
                        incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim 
                        ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco 
                        laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
                        <button>Link</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-5 col-xs-12 carousel-image">
                        <img alt="" class="img-responsive" src="http://www.placehold.it/458x376" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="background-full background-two">
                <div class="container carousel-container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-5 hidden-xs col-sm-offset-1 carousel-text">
                            <h1>Section Title 3</h1>

                            <p class="hidden-xs">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
                            consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor 
                            incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim 
                            ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco 
                            laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
                            <p class="hidden-xs">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
                            consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor 
                            incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim 
                            ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco 
                            laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
                            <button>Link</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
/*owl-nav*/
.owl-prev {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40%;
    left: 0;
}
.owl-next {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40%;
    right: 0;
}
.fa {
    font-size: 80px;
    color: #fff;
}
@media (max-width:767px) {
    .owl-nav {
        display: none;
    }
}
/*owl-dots*/
.owl-dots {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 15px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -27px;
}
.owl-dot {
    background: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    margin: 0 4px;
    text-indent: -999em;
    border-radius: 6px;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition: background .5s, opacity .5s;
    -moz-transition: background .5s, opacity .5s;
    transition: background .5s, opacity .5s;
}
.owl-dot.active {
    background: #333;
}
/*generic-carousel*/
.carousel-text, .carousel-image {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.background-full {
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 410px;
}
.background-one {
    background-image: url(http://www.placehold.it/2560x410/ff6600);
}
.background-two {
    background-image: url(http://www.placehold.it/2560x410/ff0066);
}
/*bootstap-resets*/
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .carousel-container {
    width: 970px;
    }
}
```

**Notes**:

- I'm using the Bootstrap framework.
- It must be consistent spacing from 768px up.
- Left and right percentage declarations don't make the aligment as consistent as I would like.
- I'd rather not have to put in multiple media queries to position them every so often.
- A JavaScript solution is fine.
- Any content inside the center container must be clickable etc..
- Don't worry about the layout breaking in the examples it's just to keep the code fragments above - small.
- Any other queries or clarifications, I'll be happy to update the question.

**Examples**

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xareyo/kF43L/18/)

[Full screen Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xareyo/kF43L/18/embedded/result/)

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Can't you just add some margin? What exactly would you like the result for their position to be? I'm confused on what you want to accomplish.

Comment: I just want the 'next' and 'previous' arrows to be positioned just to the right and left of the content on a consistent basis across the viewports. Margins are OK but they require constant @media declarations to keep the alignment consistent.

Comment: Ah I understand. I'm not entirely sure of your setup, but you might try creating some containers for the arrows, and another for the dots(to mimic the content) and then align the arrows in those containers.

Comment: [Here is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/xareyo/kF43L/19/embedded/result/) of the desired position I'm after if you change your viewport width to 1380px. This would need to be consistant from 768px up

Comment: I was thinking this, but Owl Carousel adds the navigation buttons via JavaScript - so i'm unsure how I would be able to wrap them?

Comment: Yes that would be problematic. You could make a `Window.onresize` event listener to change the position as it resizes, just have javascript change the left/right of the arrows based on the size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution, it may not be perfect but it works well for me. I use JavaScript to add a Bootstap, responsive container to the parent. Then on the child, holding div - match the width of it's parent on load and resize of the page.

```
$(window).on("resize load", function () {
    $('.owl-controls').addClass('container');
    $('.owl-nav').width($('.owl-nav').parent('.container').width());
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xareyo/kF43L/26/embedded/result/)